# Handling Precise Exceptions in Tomasulo

Tags: exception, mips, cpu-architecture

How are precise exceptions handled in Tomasulo's algorithm? I know one way is with the use of re-ordered buffer(ROB). I want to know what are other ways to handle precise exceptions in Tomasulo's algorithm.

Comment: Imprecise exceptions are easy to handle, you can jump to the interrupt handler routine at the time the exception is detected.  The thing that is hard is precise exceptions because you may need to roll back state that was speculatively executed.  For imprecise exceptions you don't have this constraint.

Comment: I am a beginner in this so pardon me if I am wrong. What I understand is that in out-of-order execution(completion) as in the case of Tomasulo, instruction 'j' might complete before instruction 'i' (j > i) and so if there was an divide by zero interrupt in the statement 'i' and the user sees the output of 'j' before that interrupt has been captured then he gets confused if the interrupt is handled at a later time so how to handle that scenarios in out of order architecture. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The problem you described is something where you would need a **precise** exception not an **imprecise** one.  A precise exception is associated with a specific instructions, while an imprecise exception does not have that constraint.  Imprecise exceptions are usually used for things like interrupts where you have an event that needs to be handled (such as I/O), but it's not associated with an instruction that is already in the pipeline (for those you need precise exceptions).

Comment: I got your point. So, what should be done for precise exceptions in case of out-of-order pipeline is what I want to know now.

Comment: That's what the ROB is for.  I don't know any other techniques that are used but some people might have proposed other ideas.

Comment: In-order retirement is what allows precise exceptions.  A cache miss for example will stop an instruction from retiring.  Eventually the ROB will fill up, and OOOE will stall because the ROB is full.  Potentially all but one of the instructions in the ROB are ready to retire, but can't because the oldest one is still stalled.

Comment: @GabrielSouthern: I have seen a proposal for a CPU that checkpoints occasionally.  An exception would roll back to the most recent checkpoint, instead of just to exactly that point.  This allows out-of-order retirement and thus a huge OOO window, but increases the penalty for exceptions.  I managed to remember the name of this idea so I could find the paper again: [kilo-instruction processor](http://personals.ac.upc.edu/fcazorla/articles/fcazorla_ieeemicro_kilo_2005.pdf)  That's one of several google hits for the term.  It has the graphs I remember seeing.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The proposal you have mentioned is when the re-ordered buffer gets filled. I am looking out for ways when ROB is not used.

Comment: It's not exactly "when the ROB fills", it operates differently even when the ROB isn't full: it's pretty significantly different from a standard in-order-retirement design.  It does still have a ROB, though.  Any out-of-order design needs to keep track of in-flight instructions, and whatever it uses for that purpose will be called a ROB if the name fits at all.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are alternatives that I don't know about where the term ROB might really not apply; I don't follow the CPU architecture literature at all, really.

Comment: Transmeta JITed x86 instructions into VLIW instructions for an in-order VLIW core.  Does that count?  It could internally execute x86 instructions out of order (I think), by statically re-ordering them during JIT-compilation.  I don't know for sure that they did JIT-time reordering, but it could be a major source of speedups for x86 code that wasn't software-pipelined.  This still wouldn't require a ROB, since the internal execution order is recorded in the VLIW instruction cache.  It would need some metadata to support precise exceptions, but probably not what you'd call a ROB.

Comment: here is an article I found which uses additional hardware to handle the precise exceptions:
http://www.hipc.org/hipc2002/2002Posters/Out-of-orderCommitLogic.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original Tomasulo algorithm](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/greatworks/tomasulo.pdf) does not implement precise exceptions.

Support for precise exceptions was added afterwards, see [this paper](http://impact.crhc.illinois.edu/shared/Papers/Micro-85-HPS_a_new_microarchitecture.pdf) and [this paper](http://hps.ece.utexas.edu/pub/patt2_micro18.pdf). In short, you need a **reordering for the writeback stages**.

Comment: Can you dig up links for those papers?  (and also format the list as a bullet list or with newlines or something instead of a jumble?)